# ImageView nil in PageViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, image, swift3, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to code a walkthrough for my App. I would like to change the image depending on the page. I really don't understand why, but I can't change the image from the imageView.

WalkThroughViewController:

```
class WalkThroughViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
   var mockupImage = ["iphoneWT", "iphoneWT2", "iphoneWT3", "iphoneWT4"]

func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> WalkthroughContentViewController? {
      if index < 0 || index >= mainTitleContent.count {
         return nil
      }
      if let pageContentVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WalkthroughContentViewController") as? WalkthroughContentViewController {
         pageContentVC.imageFileName = mockupImage[index]
         return pageContentVC
      }

      return nil
   }
}
```

WalkthroughContentViewController:

```
class WalkthroughContentViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    // I got an error on this line:
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageFileName)
}
```

I got this error message:

```
Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

The imageView is well linked, so it should be ok I think...

How can I understand and fix this problem?

EDIT (some screenshots):

[image]

Here it's "mockup" but I translated it to imageView in my Code to be clearer

[image]

[image]

Comment: print your imageFileName

Comment: Is you image directly copied into Xcode or is set in image assets.?

Comment: I edited my post. The image is set in image assets @AbhirajsinhThakore

Comment: did you check pageContentV` Object? I think it is nil

Comment: in which line do you have this error? imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageFileName) here?

Comment: @SergeyHleb this line: imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageFileName)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create new property, like let image = ImageView(), put your image in it, and after, for example, in viewWillApear set imageView with that image like this:

```
class WalkThroughViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
   var mockupImage = ["iphoneWT", "iphoneWT2", "iphoneWT3", "iphoneWT4"]

func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> WalkthroughContentViewController? {
      if index < 0 || index >= mainTitleContent.count {
         return nil
      }
      if let pageContentVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WalkthroughContentViewController") as? WalkthroughContentViewController {
         pageContentVC.image = mockupImage[index]
         return pageContentVC
      }
      return nil
   }
}
```

and code of WalkthroughContentViewController like here, your image property should to be here:

```
class WalkthroughContentViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    var image = UIImage()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

I think, when you try to set image for imageView, imageView is not initialized yet, and you gets nil. Let me know, if I not clear or this is not helps.

Comment: In fact the problem doesn't come from the image... I don't know why but if I want to create a new outlet, I have the same problem. And old connections are working...

Comment: if you gets nil on this line, its means only what image = nil or imageView = nil.